# How to change WordPress core language using Loco Translate?

Tags: plugins, translation, language

I just want to change the text "Add Media" to another English text. I search the text under my theme but it didn't appear.

But under Loco Translate > WordPress, there're so many translation files. Which should I edit?

See below.

[image: WordPress language files]

Comment: I went to create an English language template under that Administration language file (default->admin) shown here https://nimb.ws/FendGj and then i can't find the text "Add Media." I also searched "Media" but that text is for privacy policy.

Answer (score 0):

There are only four files in the default text domain. I found "Add Media" in the first one. (Development).

I don't recommend generating your own template. This is an advanced tool for authors. Use one of the Korean files as a template instead. You know they'll hold the correct source strings as long as your WordPress is up to date.

Click **Copy** under the Korean file > Select English > Select "Just copy English source strings" under template options.